# Why does Binary search algorithm use floor and not ceiling - not in an half open range

Tags: algorithm, search, floor, ceil

When we have an array with indexes from 0 to *n* for example.
when I use the Binary search using floor or ceiling when calculating the middle index I get the same out put.

int middle = ceiling ((left+right)/2);

Is there a reason using floor over ceiling ?
what bug will happen using the ceiling ?

Comment: The all depends on how you set the new ranges based on your evalution of the middle. With ceiling you want the new range to be either [lo, mid-1) or [mid, hi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference in complexity. Both variants are log(n).

Depending on the rest of your implementation, you may get a different result if your array looks for instance like

```
0 1 1 1 1 2
```

and looking for the index of a `1`.

Answer (score 25):

This all depends on how you update your `left` and `right` variable.

Normally, we use `left = middle+1` and `right = middle-1`, with stopping criteria `left = right`.

In this case, ceiling or flooring the middle value doesn't matter.

However, if we use `left = middle+1` and `right = middle`, we must take the floor of the middle value, otherwise we end up in an endless loop.

Consider finding `11` in array `11, 22`.

We set `left = 0` and `right = 1`, the middle is `0.5`, if we take the ceiling, it would be `1`. Since `22` is larger than query, we need to cut the right half and move right boarder towards middle. This works fine when the array is large, but since there are only two elements. `right = middle` will again set `right` to `1`. We have an infinite loop.

To sum up,

- both ceiling and flooring work fine with `left = middle+1` and `right = middle-1`
- ceiling works fine with `left = middle` and `right = middle-1`
- flooring works fine with `left = middle+1` and `right = middle`

Comment: Thank you! Been searching for an explanation just like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ceiling, this can result in an endless loop if just one element is left, because parting that range will still yield a one-element sequence. Still, you never need the middle element, so after comparison you can reduce the remaining range by that element, which will also cause the loop to terminate.

Comment: hmm. I don't fully understand this argument. Could you elaborate with an example?

Comment: I do not thing this is correct. If `left==right`, then `ceiling((left+right)/2)==floor((left+right)/2)`, so neither is useful as a loop or recursion break condition. Just `left==right` usually works.

Comment: @kkm, Do you think there is no bug using the "ceiling" function in the Binary Search algorithm?

Comment: @tal Right. Easy to try and see anyway.