# Binary search - why ceil?

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I'm studying binary search algorithm and I've seen many times the algorithm written as follows (this is C++ but the language is not that important here):

```
    int start = 0;
    int end = vec.size() - 1;       
    do {
        int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
        if (target < vec[mid])
          start = mid + 1;
        else if (target > vec[mid])
          end = mid - 1;
        else
          // found
    } while (start <= end);
```

However I've also seen implementations like this:

```
    int start = 0;
    int end = vec.size() - 1;       
    do {
        int mid = (int)ceil((lo + hi) / 2.0);
        if (target < vec[mid])
          start = mid + 1;
        else if (target > vec[mid])
          end = mid - 1;
        else
          // found
    } while (start <= end);
```

Both seem to work. Is there any correctness or performance reason why I should get the `ceil` and do that second case floating point arithmetic instead of using the first version?

Comment: Note that you can avoid floating-point with `(lo + hi + 1) / 2`.

Comment: This is basically answered here I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655955/why-does-binary-search-algorithm-use-floor-and-not-ceiling-not-in-an-half-open (thus tempted to mark as duplicate).

Comment: Note that your midpoint formula is *wrong* because `left + right` risks overflow. Better to do: `(int)(((unsigned)lo + (unsigned)hi) / 2)` which gives you the desired two's-complement wrap-around behavior. (See also [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/152085/bisection-method/152136#152136), though it is in the context of C#. Plenty of information about this available online via Google.)

Comment: @CodyGray: Actually, making **indices** `unsigned` (or better yet, `size_t`) *right from the start* would be the logical thing to do...

Comment: Kaidul's answer is correct, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416560/how-can-i-simplify-this-working-binary-search-code-in-c/39417165#39417165

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `int mid = (lo + hi) / 2`:

You are deciding the `mid` element by taking the left element of the two potential middle elements when the array size between [left, right] is odd i.e. for array [4, 5] your mid will be 4. So without any `ceil` of `floor`, the division works pretty like `floor`.

When `(int)ceil((lo + hi) / 2.0);`:

You are deciding the `mid` element by taking the right element of the two potential middle elements when the array size between [left, right] is odd i.e. for [4, 5] your mid will be 5.

So both selection will work because you're discarding/taking a part based on some valid conditions (`target < vec[mid]` and `target > vec[mid]`), The partition point won't matter here that much.

Another thing is, during operation like `int mid = (lo + hi) / 2` you may encounter overflow when adding `lo` and `hi` if the summation exceeds integer range. So safe is to write like `mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2` which will yield same output.

Hope it helps!

### Edit

> so both work only because I'm discarding the mid element from the new
>   search range when restarting the search, right?

Yes. If you wouldn't discard the `mid` element, it will fall into infinity loop i.e. [4, 5], 4 would be always selected as `mid` and for call like `left = mid`, it would create an infinite loop.

Comment: so both work only because I'm **discarding** the mid element from the new search range when restarting the search, right? (otherwise there might be an infinite loop)